# eval func not run sequentially in make receipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
.PHONY: set-var
set-var: 
        set -e; \
        $(foreach fru, $(mylist), \
          if [ -z ${eggshell} ]; then \
            $(PYTHON) foo.py \
          else \
            $(PYTHON) foo-eggshell.py \

          fi;) \
        $(eval egg_number = $(shell cat egg.log))
```

`foo.py` and `foo-eggshell.py` generates `egg.log` file
for some reason when this target is called eval statement gets called before the file is generated; failed with no such file for egg.log

how do I ensure `eval` gets called only after the above python scripts are run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, in the same rule.  In make, the entire recipe is expanded first, then each line of the recipe is passed to the shell.  So, the `eval` function is expanded before any part of the recipe is passed to the shell.

I don't really know what you're trying to do here, but the only way to have `eval` invoked after the recipe is run is to put it into a separate recipe (that is, have one rule that runs the python script and list that rule as a prerequisite of a rule that uses `eval` in its recipe.

In general it's a bad idea to try to use `eval` inside a recipe and to set make variables to values generated by recipes.  It can work in very specific situations but it's also limited.

Comment: yes, i ended up having it as a separte recipe

separately, can you elaborate why it's a bad idea to use eval inside recipe?

Comment: As long as you're very clear on where that variable is valid and where it is not valid, it should work.  For example you cannot use that variable in any target or prerequisite, nor to compute any target or prerequisite, and you have to be sure that (a) that target is a prerequisite of every rule where the recipe wants to use that variable, **AND** (b) that target is declared PHONY or you're sure that the recipe is invoked for some other reason every time you want to use the variable (if it's up to date the recipe won't run and the variable won't be set).

Comment: In general IMO it's cleaner and more reliable to use shell constructs to retrieve the value in other recipes where it's needed, rather than using `eval` to set a make variable.  But, since you don't describe your use case maybe it's not a problem.